# "Согласно постановлению" — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

*Согласно постановлению, школы будут специализироваться как минимум на одном предмете, и в них не реже одного раза в неделю будет проводиться тестирование.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая запятая не нужна, поскольку "согласно постановлению" общий член, оба условия выполняются согласно этому постановлению.

Первая запятая факультативна.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что первая запятая крайне важна, так как без нее конструкция **"Согласно постановлению школы"** может быть воспринята в начале прочтения как единое целое, т.е. школа выпустила некое постановление, согласно которому развивается дальнейшее действие. И лишь при продолжении чтения появляется возможность понять, о чем шла речь в начале предложения.

Вторая запятая не нужна.